# Devise: Updating user without password not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I've done what Devise's github wiki article says on the topic, by adding the below to my freshly generated registrations_controller file (haven't touched anything else in there):

```
protected

def update_resource(resource, params)
  resource.update_without_password(params)
end
```

I've done my routing by adding `controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }` (it's in controllers/users folder) to my routes files but all I get is an error, saying `unknown attribute 'current_password' for User` when I try to update my user.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need to remove field  'current_password' from your devise/regristrations/edit.html.erb file

Comment: This, right here, makes so much sense that I'm going to bang my head against the wall a few times. I feel ashamed. Thanks so much, @GauravGupta!!!